# Going for a Conference, but applying for Multiple Entry Visas

Tags: schengen, applications, multiple-entry, nigerian-citizens

I have a conference invitation already, but I want to always go and come into the Schengen territory (maybe when I am on holiday), is it wise I apply for Multiple Entry Schengen visas other than Single Entry? I am From Nigeria.

How wise is this?

Answer (score 1):

You’d need to demonstrate a reason (other than just a desire) for multiple entry. If this is your first Schengen application, and the main premise is to attend the conference, then your chance of success would be greater if you applied for a single entry visa, IMHO. On the other hand, if you have a strong travel history and good ties to home/financial circumstances, a multiple entry application could succeed.